# Notation for fiber bundles - why E for total space?

Tags: notation

I'm looking for info on why E is commonly used for the total space of a fiber bundle. I understand F (fiber) and B (base), but there doesn't seem to be any particularly obvious reason for choosing E.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Early contributors to the theory of fiber bundles, like Ehresmann who developed the geometric formalism of general connections, were French. In French total space is [espace étalé](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C3%A9tal%C3%A9+space). In more refined terminology espace étalé is something more structured, which only coincides with the total space as a set, and applies to sheaves, which generalize fiber bundles. This generalization was also developed by the French, espace étalé definition was used in the [1950 Cartan seminar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#History).

Comment: In French total space is [espace total](//fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibré). (That’s already all the E we need.)